# Error under Ubuntu with the method String.join

Tags: java, string, ubuntu, join

I use the lib `commons-lang-2.4.jar` for my project.
I develop under Windows, then send everything (including those libs) to Ubuntu server 4.6.3
Under windows, everything works fine.
But when I launch my program under Ubuntu, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.join(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;[Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you run the program ?

Comment: Your exception shows that you are calling join on a string(java.lang.String) object. I don't think String has a join method. But this should be shown as compile error in eclipse. How are you coding your project?

Comment: @Nazgul - `String` has a `join` method, but it was only introduced in JDK 1.8.

Comment: yes i know. I presumed the OP is on JDK7. My Bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) was only introduced in Java 8 (JDK 1.8). Your windows machine apparently has it, while your ubuntu machine has an older version of the JDK installed. This has nothing to do with their respective operating systems or `commons-lang-2.4.jar`.

TL;DR - upgrade to JDK 1.8 on your ubuntu machine.